# how to share variables inside and outside of async functions?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I am having trouble with async in nodejs.
In the following code

```
//Imagine we are inside a function
// many things here before reading a file
 this.data_receiver;    //want to this get file content
 fs.readFile('/data.txt', (err, data) => {
   if (err) throw err;
    //console.log(data);
     this.data_receiver= data;  // get data
});

//I want to process data_receiver
......
```

The problem is that how can I get data little by little from a file and store it into some variables, then use that variable outside?

I am new to this async, having trouble.

Comment: What do you mean by "get data little by little"?

Comment: @RoumelisGeorge I mean if I am reading ti piece by piece, not all at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `this` is not bounded to your function inside the callback. You should do:

```js
this.data_receiver;    //want to this get file content
var me = this;
fs.readFile('/data.txt', (err, data) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  //console.log(data);
  me.data_receiver = data;  // get data
});
console.log(this.data_receiver);
```

Also, this is about callback scope. While technically saying, it is "async functions", but it is more common to associate "async functions" to `async` functions, such as:

```js
async function foo() {
  return Promise.resolve();
}
```

Comment: If above code is inside a function. If I wanted to use this.data_receiver immediately after calling that function, how do I know if this.data_receiver got data?

Comment: While the structure is "async" (callback), JavaScript is single thread thus the callback is called before the `readFile()` returns.

Comment: I also want to point out that your concern is legit. The code work because it knows something implicit -- that it is running in a single thread environment. The better structure is to use structure such as Promise.